# Colour a cell if a certain number is entered

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I need to program a conditional format in Excel 2016 without using the existing conditional formatting tool.

I want to write this e.g. in a private sub:

for range A1:A100:
- If value is >=1 then colour = green
- If value is <1 or "" then colour red

for range B1:B100
- If value is >=3 then colour = green
- If value is <3 & >0 then colour yellow
- if value is  0 or "" the colour red

My code. When I save it, nothing happens in my second defined range, also after reopening the Excel workbook:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rngObserve As Range, rngCell As Range

Set rngObserve = Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100"))

If rngObserve Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each rngCell In rngObserve.Cells
    If Not Intersect(rngCell, rngObserve) Is Nothing Then

        If rngCell.Value = vbNullString Then
            rngCell.Interior.Color = xlNone

        ElseIf rngCell.Value < 1 Then
            rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'red

        ElseIf rngCell.Value >= 1 Then
            rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'green

        Else
            rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End If
Next

Set rngObserve = Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B100"))

If rngObserve Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each rngCell In rngObserve.Cells

    If Not Intersect(rngCell, rngObserve) Is Nothing Then

        If rngCell.Value = vbNullString Then
            rngCell.Interior.Color = xlNone

        ElseIf rngCell.Value < 1& > 0 Then
            rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'yellow

        ElseIf rngCell.Value >= 3 Then
            rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'green

        Else
            rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Please note *"does not work"* is no useful error description. Please [edit] your question and include: Which error do you get and where? Also `Range("A")` is no valid range it must be `Range("A:A")` or `Columns("A")` if you mean column A. `MyPlage As Range` is missing a `Dim`. Also you might want to have a look at the [Select...Case Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement).

Comment: Your code cannot even compile as you are missing an `End If`. If you want to use `WorksheetChange` you can't change the name and you must place it in the relevant sheet module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following macro. It must the placed in the respective worksheet (not the workbook and not in a module). Moreover, you can define a range to observe by defining rngObserve). I guess you don't want to check the whole worksheet...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rngObserve As Range, rngCell As Range

Set rngObserve = Intersect(Target, Range("A1:C5"))

If rngObserve Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If
For Each rngCell In rngObserve.Cells
    If Not Intersect(rngCell, rngObserve) Is Nothing Then
        If rngCell.Value = vbNullString Then
            rngCell.Interior.Color = xlNone
        ElseIf rngCell.Value < 1 Then
            rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        ElseIf rngCell.Value >= 1 Then
            rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Else
            rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Doesn't an empty cell have a value of zero (*less than 1*)?

Comment: Yes. And if emil7 doesn't want emptied cells being marked red he can adjust the formatting pattern.

Comment: you could use `Set rngObserve = Intersect(Target, Range("A1:C5"))` and `For Each rngCell In rngObserve` so you would only have one `Intersect` that should speed it up a lot. Of course test `If rngObserve Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` after `Set` it.

Comment: Thank you so much! How could I add a second range (e.g. A1:B10 & K18:K30)? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: You can define more complex ranges by separating them with commas. E.g. "A1:B10,K18:K30"

Comment: @emil7 I'm glad I can help. Please upvote/select as answer if your happy with the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. You must use the Worksheet_Change Event. You cannot rename that event!
2. Use `Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("A:A"))` to get only the cells in column A.
3. Test each cell value in `Target` if it is a number `If IsNumeric(Cell.Value) Then` to make sure it works on number values only!

So you end up with something like:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim MyPlage  As Range
    Set MyPlage = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("A:A"))

    If Not MyPlage Is Nothing Then
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In MyPlage
            If Cell.Value = vbNullString Then
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'red
            ElseIf IsNumeric(Cell.Value) Then
                If Cell.Value < 1 Then
                    Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'red
                Else
                    Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'green
                End If
            End If
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: fwiw, a blank cell IsNumeric and has a value less than 1 (considered zero). e.g. IsNumeric(<blank cell>) is true and  <blank cell>.value = 0.

Comment: @user10779473 Totally correct, thanks! I switched the `If … ElseIf`. Nevertheless I kept the `IsNumeric` to ensure it runs on numeric values only (can easily be removed if not needed).

Answer (score 0):

You need `Range("A:A")` but that would be better if it were cut down to the cells within the worksheet's UsedRange property. Additionally, a blank cell's value is considered zero so that condition should be checked first.

```
dim MyPlage As Range, cell as range

Set MyPlage = intersect(activesheet.Range("A:A"), activesheet.UsedRange)

For Each Cell In MyPlage

    If isempty(cell) then
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'red
    elseIf Cell.Value < 1 Then
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'red
    ElseIf Cell.Value >= 1 Then
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'green
    end if

Next cell
```

I've separated the empty cells and the cells with a value less than one because although they are for all intents and purposes the same thing, you might want to choose a different color for one of them in the future.

It might be easier to set all to vbRed then selectively set values greater or equal to 1 as vbGreeen.

```
dim MyPlage As Range, cell as range

Set MyPlage = intersect(activesheet.Range("A:A"), activesheet.UsedRange)

MyPlage.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'red 

For Each Cell In MyPlage

    If  Cell.Value >= 1 Then
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'green
    end if

Next cell
```

Comment: Note that using `ActiveSheet` in the `Worksheet_Change` event is dangerous. `ActiveSheet` is NOT the sheet that triggered the event BUT the sheet that is on top at the moment the code runs. If the event eg. is triggered by a VBA statement like `Range("A1").Value = 5` then the `ActiveSheet` might be a completely different sheet.

Comment: Very true and that is not a practice to be advocated. My response was not to fix a Worksheet_Change event sub but rather a public or private sub to be run on the active sheet.

Comment: Just wanted to mention it to avoid the OP using it in combination with `Worksheet_Change`. Note that your second code also turns strings into red which are usually not `<1`.

Comment: Good point about the strings. I had assumed that the OP only wanted to deal with numbers and blanks (per original code) but that was wrong. In fact, those `""` could be zero-length strings left by a formula in which case they are not considered 'empty'.. Also, good mention about the fallacy of relying on ActiveSheet within a triggered sub procedure.